# When to declarate a variable issue

Tags: c

Can someone explain me the most simple way the meaning of this syntax of C?

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(number[i]<number[j])
        {
            aux=number[i];
            number[i]=number[j];
            number[j]=aux;
        }
    }
}
```

I just trying to figure out I know is an iteration or a loop but specifically aux is a var. Why i need to follow this i'm trying to get pos and negs, into an array but this part i'm stuck is there another way ?

I just need to figure this syntax.

Comment: Looks like a bubble sort. It swaps values until the entire array is sorted. If you're just looking to put positive numbers into one array and negative numbers into another, you don't really need this.

Comment: You are just swapping values of `number[i]` and `number[j]` only if `number[i]<number[j]`.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out what this does and/or do you have specific problem you need to solve? Is this an assignment?

Comment: wow that was fast thanks for your help!

Comment: im solving some type of homework, i didnt know was a bubble sort, i know now thanks, i will review that algorithm i was kind of confuse need to clear out this thing :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). `aux` is a temporary variable used for exchanging the values of `number[i]` and `number[j]`. You can't do

```
number[i] = number[j];
number[j] = number[i];
```

to exchange the two, as both would be equal to `number[j]` this way. So you need a temporary variable.

Comment: ok will check it out thanks for the help !

Comment: you can, however, do this if you want to avoid the temporary variable:

    number[i] ^= number[j];
    number[j] ^= number[i];
    number[i] ^= number[j];